# CSS: change background opacity for a child div having same background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a framing effect as shown in the image. All i want is to change background opacity inside a div. Here is what I tried,

```
.parent {
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 }
.child {
   background-color:transparent;
 }
```

But its not working

html

```
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Xpress Music</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Express.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper main">
<div class="main_box">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo.png" width="8%">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper1">
      <div class="frame" style="font-size:2vw;border-width:0px;margin-top:-10%;">COMING SOON...</div>
      <div class="frame frame1"></div>
      <div class="frame" style="border-width:0px;">
          <div class="field">
            <form action="/subscribe" method="get">
              <input type="submit" name="search" value="Go" style="float: right" />
              <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .5em;">
                <input type="text" name="term" style="width: 100%;" />
               </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body{
    background-image: url('big-image.jpg')  ; 
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: gunplay;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: gunplay;
    src: url(gunplay.ttf);
}
.logo{
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: 2%;
}
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  border:9px solid #f4f4f4;
}
.frame1, .frame4 {
    border-width: 12px;
}
.frame2, .frame3 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.frame4 {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.frame1 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
}
.main:after {
    padding-top: 55.62%;
}
.main_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

[image]

This is the entire part of my code.

Comment: post your html code..

Comment: what is `.parent` and what is `.child` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors.

It's an awkward one but you can do it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/uLaa9fnu/1/

```css
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url('http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Outdoors/Landscapes/landscapes-267a.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: gunplay;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.frame {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/4AcIXsD.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height:340px;
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(50% - 150px);
    top:calc(50% - 170px);
}
.frame:before {
    content:'';
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1000%;
    top:-1000%;
    bottom:-1000%;
    right:100%;
}
.frame:after {
    content:'';
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:-1000%;
    top:-1000%;
    bottom:-1000%;
    left:100%;
}
.frame2 {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.frame2:before {
    content:'';
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-1000%;
    bottom:100%;
    right:0;
}
.frame2:after {
    content:'';
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:100%;
    bottom:-1000%;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="frame">
        <div class="frame2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically you use the `before` and `after` on the main `.frame` element to put overlay opacity over the left and right, and then you put an element within that set to the same size that use `before` and `after` to put overlay opacity at the top and bottom.

Also the `overflow:hidden;` on the body (or whatever the parent will be) is important otherwise you'll have long scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But I have multiple frames in the same page. I am not sure this will work for multiple. Can we have multiple frames with this css?

Comment: Multiple frames on the same background? Or multiple images with frames on? The latter can be achieved quite easily: http://jsfiddle.net/uLaa9fnu/1/

Comment: @user2772004 Also, I know I've built the example responsively, but will it be responsive or will it have a fixed height and width?

Comment: Multiple frames. See the requirement is we have a single background and we have frames at different places.

Comment: In future you need to try and make sure you put ALL your requirements in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82687/discussion-between-user2772004-and-jamie-barker).

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

```
opacity:0.5;
```

Or whatever value you want the opacity to be

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it kind of difficult to work out what exactly you're trying to achieve, but the code you provided seems to work fine as far as I can tell?

http://jsfiddle.net/rhuzuu1z/

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: navy;
}
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 }
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

The bordered 'child' div is transparent, showing it's parents background and the 'parent' div is translucent allowing some of the containers background colour to pass through.

Comment: But actually in this case I need navy as child background and its not color its image. Same image as background of child but parent is some what blured or opacity change.

Comment: So you want the child and the parent to take on the background image of the container, but the child being clear and the parent being translucent?

Comment: Exactly, thats what i want.

Comment: There's no real way to do exactly that using the structure you have. What sort of browser support are you looking for?

Comment: Browser support is flexible. I am looking for latest versions of firefox, chrome and safari.

Comment: Ok, how about something like this, with just a parent that has a background image, and a child with a translucent border. The way the demo is set up is very basic so you could work on making it responsive. http://jsfiddle.net/rhuzuu1z/1/

Answer (score 0):

This Is Done With Canvas Filters. You Can Do This With This Code:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="can" width="1024" height="786" style="border: 1px dashed black"></canvas>
<img id="img" src="./IMAGE_NAME.jpg" style="display:none">
```

**JS**

```
onload = function(){
    var can = document.getElementById('can');
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.getElementById('img');

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, can.width, can.height);

    var id = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
    var d = id.data;

    var bw = 100; // The Darker Border Width In Pixels

    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
        if(i % (can.width * 4) / 4 < bw || i % (can.width * 4) / 4 > can.width - bw || i < bw * can.width * 4 || i > (can.height - bw) * can.width * 4 ){
            d[i]     -= 100; // red
            d[i + 1] -= 100; // green
            d[i + 2] -= 100; // blue
            d[i + 3] -= 100; // alpha
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
}
```

**NOTE:**  If Your Picture Is not From Your Domain It Fails. Run This Code On A Local Web Server Or Provide A Base-64 Image Data To img Tag. Take A Look At This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/b4Lwt4k5/)